# How to download a file using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: java, javascript

I am posting html content to  the serverside and converting it to PDF and streaming the file back. 
But am not able to download the file using:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("htmlContent", strHTML);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "RenderHtmlAsPDF.jsp");
request.send(formData);
```

Download works when I create a dynamic form and post the html content targeting it to an iframe. But I am limited by the amount of data I can send.

Comment: Sadly file download don't work with ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can't download a file with AJAX. However you can "simulate" the behaviour by doing the folowing: make the ajax post request for file generation, after the file was generated on the server, generate a token or id with witch you can identify the file, send it back to the client and when you have received the response token on the client simply generate an iframe with the src pointing to a method on your back-end which receives the token and sends back the file.